# Applications of the Mean Value Theorem in different mathematical and physical phenomena

Tags: calculus

It has been a few months since I started digging deeper into the concepts of Fundamental Calculus. It is interesting to understand the theorems, and their applications in either proving mathematical statements or understanding a mathematical model of a natural phenomenon.

The most potent theorem I have encountered till date is the Mean Value Theorem for continuous and differentiatiable functions.

While I do understand the proof to a good extent, I often find myself unable to realize its applications in several problems. I realize that as a beginner I need more practice.

I was wondering if I could be introduced to several applications( in any field of analysis ) of this theorem. That way, my understanding of this theorem will strengthen significantly.

Comment: I believe that you are using the Intermediate value theorem for continuous functions. How is the Mean Value Theorem used here?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I'll delete the comment